# check Timer time in game

Tags: android, timer

In my game I give 5 seconds to answer each question. If a user selects the correct answer then I show him/her the next question. If a user can't answer the question, the level is set to the first question (each question is a level).

How can I put a timer in my code?

Comment: Use a CountDownTimer

Comment: Please read the android API reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html In case you encounter a specific problem, adjust your question accordingly

Comment: How I can check that user select true answer in range 0-5 second?

Answer (score 0):

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timertask;
timer = new Timer();
timertask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // add your code here that will run after 5 seconds.        
            }
        });
    }
};
timer.schedule(timertask, 5000);
```

Use timer task for scheduling the execution. For more info Check Here [Timer Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) and [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html)

Comment: How I can check that user select true answer in range 0-5 second?

Comment: Above code will run after 5 seconds and if you want to know that user has selected the correct answer or not within 0-5 seconds you have to add click listener on your submit answer button which will check if the answer is correct or not.

Comment: If user select answer before 5 sec how can handle it?

Comment: let me explain you.
There is a question with options and when user select one of your option, you check the correctness of answer either on option selected or on button(if you provide to submit answer). And if user does not select or submit any answer with in 5 seconds then your timer task will run.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem!

Comment: For this add click listener on Submit button.

Comment: This is my project info: 1 textview ; 3 button and 1 progressbar

Answer (score 0):

From [Android developper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) :

```
CountDownTimer myCountDown = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
 }

 public void onFinish() {
     mTextField.setText("done!");
 }
}.start();
```

You can use these callbacks to handle ticks and the end of timer.

The first paramter determinates the duration of the timer.

The second parameter of CountDownTimer determinates the duration of one tick until the end.

**EDIT:**

If you need to stop the timer before the end of your 5 seconds, you can store the current time before launch your countdown:

```
final long timeBeforeLaunchCountDown = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

So, when a click occurs (user answers to your question), you can just compare the new current time with your previous time and stop the countDown:

```
if((System.currentTimeMillis() - timeBeforeLaunchCountDown) > 5000){
    myCountDown.cancel();
}
```

Comment: how to get CountDownTimer value for compare with System.currentTimeMillis() ?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible directly but you can store the current time when you launch your timer then you can compare when a click occurs the new current time if less than the referenced current time + 5 seconds

Comment: Why do you want to `compare`? The CountDownTimer does it for you! Once started, just forget about it.

Comment: Because maybe sometimes, you want stop the timer before is finish and before it does his onFinish method, it could be useful to compare with the time. If you wait always the end of timer to get the answer, ok. Don't compare.